# RequestActivityUpdates takes way longer than detection interval

Tags: android, activity-recognition

I'm currently developing an app that uses the activity recogition api.
I have a main activity and an intent service which is called using requestActivityUpdates() and returns data for the activity using the broadcast api.

According to the documentation, requestActivityUpdates' first parameter, detectionIntervalMillis, stands for "the desired time between activity detections. Larger values will result in fewer activity detections while improving battery life. A value of 0 will result in activity detections at the fastest possible rate.".

I'm using a values as low as 100ms and still I get updates once every 3 minutes on average. What could be the problem here? I tested on 2 different fully charged devices already, so I believe this has nothing to do with power saving configurations.

edit: took the devices for a walk and it seems that the rate of updates go up to ~8s. Still way more than expected. :/